How can install audiorelay when is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source?
OS version info:
uname -a
Linux MiWiFi-R4A-srv 6.1.0-18-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.76-1 (2024-02-01) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Download audiorelay and install:
wget   https://dl.audiorelay.net/setups/linux/audiorelay-0.27.5.deb
sudo dpkg -i   audiorelay-0.27.5.deb

Error info Package libflac8 is not installed:
Selecting previously unselected package audiorelay.
(Reading database ... 352042 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack audiorelay-0.27.5.deb ...
Unpacking audiorelay (0.27.5-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of audiorelay:
 audiorelay depends on libflac8; however:
  Package libflac8 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package audiorelay (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 audiorelay

To install libflac8:
sudo apt install  libflac8
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package libflac8 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libflac8' has no installation candidate

How can install audiorelay?

libflac8 is still available in Debian 11, you can download and install it from there:
wget http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/f/flac/libflac8_1.3.3-2+deb11u2_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./libflac8_1.3.3-2+deb11u2_amd64.deb

Debian 11 is still fully supported for another two weeks, and after that it will get long-term support (on a reduced set of packages) for another two years, so you should check periodically for updates to the libflac8 package.
